# Converting an NSString to and from UTF32

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring

I'm working with a database that includes hex codes for UTF32 characters. I would like to take these characters and store them in an NSString. I need to have routines to convert in both ways.

To convert the first character of an NSString to a unicode value, this routine seems to work:

```
const unsigned char *cs = (const unsigned char *)
    [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
uint32_t code = 0;
for ( int i = 3 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
    code <<= 8;
    code += cs[i];
}
return code;
```

However, I am unable to do the reverse (i.e. take a single code and convert it into an NSString). I thought I could just do the reverse of what I do above by simply creating a c-string with the UTF32 character in it with the bytes in the correct order, and then create an NSString from that using the correct encoding.

However, converting to / from cstrings does not seem to be reversible for me.

For example, I've tried this code, and the "tmp" string is not equal to the original string "s".

```
char *cs = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithCString:cs encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using "wchar_t" for the cstring instead of char *?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a couple of reasonable options.

### 1. Conversion

The first is to convert your UTF32 to UTF16 and use those with NSString, as UTF16 is the "native" encoding of NSString. It's not actually all that hard. If the UTF32 character is in the BMP (e.g. it's high two bytes are 0's), you can just cast it to `unichar` directly. If it's in any other plane, you can convert it to a surrogate pair of UTF16 characters. You can find the rules on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2). But a quick (untested) conversion would look like

```
UTF32Char inputChar = // my UTF-32 character
inputChar -= 0x10000;
unichar highSurrogate = inputChar >> 10; // leave the top 10 bits
highSurrogate += 0xD800;
unichar lowSurrogate = inputChar & 0x3FF; // leave the low 10 bits
lowSurrogate += 0xDC00;
```

Now you can create an NSString using both characters at the same time:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(unichar[]){highSurrogate, lowSurrogate} length:2];
```

To go backwards, you can use `[NSString getCharacters:range:]` to get the unichar's back and then reverse the surrogate pair algorithm to get your UTF32 character back (any characters which aren't in the range `0xD800-0xDFFF` should just be cast to UTF32 directly).

### 2. Byte buffers

Your other option is to let NSString do the conversion directly without using cStrings. To convert a UTF32 value into an NSString you can use something like the following:

```
UTF32Char inputChar = // input UTF32 value
inputChar = NSSwapHostIntToLittle(inputChar); // swap to little-endian if necessary
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&inputChar length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

To get it back out again, you can use

```
UTF32Char outputChar;
if ([str getBytes:&outputChar maxLength:4 usedLength:NULL encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 1) remainingRange:NULL]) {
    outputChar = NSSwapLittleIntToHost(outputChar); // swap back to host endian
    // outputChar now has the first UTF32 character
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great reply!!! I had to modify your last routine slightly to use the result from rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex: for the range since some single characters are actually composed of two unichars. After reading your reply, I also found the routines CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair() and CFStringGetSurrogatePairForLongCharacter() which also seem useful. One strange result with your code above, however, is that in your examples above, initWithBytes: and stringWithCharacters: both returned nil for my "large" utf32 value.

Comment: @Ron: I didn't actually test option 2, just option 1. Still, I'm surprised you're getting nil back. What value are you testing with? Note that UTF32 only goes up to 0x10FFFF, so if you're trying a higher value then it shouldn't work. I also just ran across `CFStringGetSurrogatePairForLongCharacter` myself and was considering rewriting my answer to include it, but it sounds like you already know how to use it.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm pretty sure that the code I passed in was a valid unicode value (it was a value I had just received from using your code to convert the character to unicode and I looked it up to make sure it was valid). I think one value I was looking at was 0x26951. No NSLog messages or anything ... just returned nil. Anyway, thanks to your help, I do have my code working perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to repsond!

Comment: @Ron: Ah hah, it's the endianness. `NSUTF32StringEncoding` doesn't declare which endianness it is. On little-endian machines (e.g. modern Macs), you can use `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding` instead. You can also use `NSSwapHostIntToLittle()` to ensure the input is in little-endian format.

Comment: @Kevin - hmm ... it could be the endian-ness. However, it seems strange that the NSUTF32StringEncoding would be inconsistent. One thing I tried was the latter two solutions you have above where one converts to bytes using NSUTF32StringEncoding, and then I immediately try to convert back using the same encoding. You would think that the endian-ness would be the same. Either way, I really appreciate your answers, and I am very happy that I have an solution now that I have tested both ways for all of the characters that I care about. Thanks!

Comment: @Ron: It's possible that NSUTF32StringEncoding wants to use a BOM, while `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding` and `NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding` don't.

Comment: @Kevin: hmm ... that would make sense. Didn't think of the BOM.

Comment: Possibly, `NSMakeRange(0, 1)` should be `NSMakeRange(0, str.length)`, otherwise I'm not getting much success at getting my bytes back.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

### 1:

The first one is that both `[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]` and `[NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding:]` return the C-string in native-endianness (little) **without adding a BOM to it** when using `NSUTF32StringEncoding` and `NSUTF16StringEncoding`.

[The Unicode standard states that](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom10): (see, "How I should deal with BOMs")

`"If there is no BOM, the text should be interpreted as big-endian."`

This is also stated in [NSString's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring): (see, "Interpreting UTF-16-Encoded Data")

`"... if the byte order is not otherwise specified, NSString assumes that the UTF-16 characters are big-endian, unless there is a BOM (byte-order mark), in which case the BOM dictates the byte order."`

Although they're referring to UTF-16, the same applies to UTF-32.

### 2:

The second one is that `[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]` internally uses `CFStringCreateWithCString` to create the C-string. The problem with this is that `CFStringCreateWithCString` only accepts strings using **8-bit encodings**. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542942-cfstringcreatewithcstring?language=objc): (see, "Parameters" section)

`The string must use an 8-bit encoding.`

### To solve this issue:

1. Explicitly state the encoding endianness you want to use both ways (`NSString -> C-string` and `C-string -> NSString`)
2. Use `[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]` when trying to create an NSString from a C-string encoded in UTF-32 or UTF-16.