# Convert U+ unicode to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode-string

I am referring to this table (https://unicodey.com/emoji-data/table.htm) and want to convert a `U+1F1E6 U+1F1FA` code to display it in `NSString`. How can I do that? I don't have the \u format unicode otherwise it would work automatically.

Comment: Related: [Converting an NSString to and from UTF32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458708/)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you mean you're scraping the HTML? Are you constructing the string in code or are you trying to convert the HTML to a string programmatically? Give an example of actual input and desired output.

Comment: @matt: The emojis are being stored in :xxx: format in our database and so in app it is not being able to parse the :xxx: slack emoji format. So, I am referring the emoji table to gather the mapping for the slack emoji format to supported unicode format in app. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` is encoded as UTF-16, so `U+1F1E6 U+1F1FA` can be expressed in code using `\u` notation: `"\uD83C\uDDE6\uD83C\uDDFA"`.  Or, if you use `\U` notation instead, you can use the actual codepoints as-is: `"\U0001F1E6\U0001F1FA"`.

In Swift, it would be expressed as `"\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1FA}"` instead.

In either case, you can alternatively just put the Unicode characters directly in the string literal and not escape them at all: `""`.

Comment: There are also `\Unnnnnnnn` escape sequences: `@"\U0001F1E6\U0001F1FA"`

Comment: @Remy: Thanks for the explanation. Only required thing now is a way to convert the U+1F1E6 U+1F1FA to its unicode "\uD83C\uDDE6\uD83C\uDDFA". Do you know a way to convert this?

Comment: @Shaunak that is a very simple calculation. Read the UTF-16 spec, or the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description)